# Convert string back to ObjectID

Tags: php, mongodb

I have converted a ObjectID to string which acts as a dropdown list value. When posted I need to take this string and convert it back to a ObjectID in the cleanest fashion.

What would be the best way of doing this?

Comment: Oops, I was wrong. Apparently, MongoID is the class name for ObjectID in PHP driver. But your tag was wrong anyways :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that MongoID class [accepts a string in the constructor](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/mongoid.construct.php):

```
public MongoId::__construct ([ string $id = NULL ] )
```

> #### id
>
> A string to use as the id. Must be 24 hexidecimal characters. If an invalid string is passed to this constructor, the constructor will ignore it and create a new id value.